# Point of batch_size in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Let's say that I have 1000 grayscale images of size `25x25` that I would like to train on, and my `batch_size` is set to 20. From what I understand, this means that the algorithm will take the first 20 samples, and train the network. Then, it will take the next 20, and train the network. It will keep doing this until all 1000 images have been fed through the network. That is ONE epoch. This is repeated for however many epochs I want.

My question is as follows:

Why does the `batch_size` make a difference? The way I see it, the network can only train one example at a time. The input layer consists of `625 = 25x25` neurons, so what do people mean when they say that the `batch_size` allows the network to train 20 data points at once?

Whether the `batch_size` is 5, 10, or 100, the network has to process each image **one-by-one**, so I don't really see the advantage?

Answer (score 1):

The batch size has two purposes (that I know of, there could be more):

1. It facilitates vectorized operations, and thus speeds up training. Processing single examples would take too much time and processing the whole training data at once brings memory problems. Therefore, you train `batch_size` examples at a time.
2. Since the objective/loss function is calculated on multiple examples at once, and the errors are backpropagated, the parameters are updated with regards to the errors for many examples and the loss curve does not fluctuate as much as it would with single examples each time. Thus, you would reach the global optimum faster and the curve would be smooth.